# How to place the block button at the end of the page in ionic 5

Tags: css, ionic-framework, flexbox

Here i am trying to place the the button signin and other button at the end of the page using ionic and i am using the ionic css utilities but i am not sure why it is not changing
i want [image: Button]

here is my code

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" class="ion-text-center">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
         <ion-list>
           <ion-item detail>
            <ion-icon name="settings-outline">

            </ion-icon>
              Settings
           </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
        
      </ion-col>

     
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-self-end">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button> Register Button</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
     
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-self-end">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" >Sign Button</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
     
    </ion-row>
    
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: i think you can use `ion-footer` ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid style="height: 100%; display: grid;" size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" class="ion-text-center">

    <ion-row> 
      <ion-col>
         <ion-list>
           <ion-item detail>
            <ion-icon name="settings-outline">
            </ion-icon>
              Settings
           </ion-item>
         </ion-list>          
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="ion-align-self-end">
      <ion-col><ion-button> Register Button</ion-button>
        <ion-button expand="block" >Sign Button</ion-button>
      </ion-col>       
    </ion-row>
    
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use power of CSS flexbox to achieve that like so:

```
    <ion-content>

        <ion-grid size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%">

            <ion-row style="flex-grow: 1">
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-list>
                        <ion-item detail>
                            <ion-icon name="settings-outline">
                            </ion-icon>
                            Settings
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row class="ion-align-self-center">
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button> Register Button</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row class="ion-align-self-center">
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button expand="block">Sign Button</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

        </ion-grid>

    </ion-content>
```

Basically you make your ion-grid element to display as flexbox in column and set height to occupy 100% of height.

Then you can apply "flex-grow: 1" to an ion-row to make it stretch across all available space. In your case you only need to give that to the first ion-row.

Other options could be playing with display: absolute and bottom: 0 in your CSS.